# PHP OOP- inject DB class to a construct method of another class

Tags: php

I have a `Database` class for connecting to DB.

```
 <?php

require_once('config.php');

class Database {

   function __construct(){
     $this->connect();
   }

   public function connect(){
     $this->connection = mysqli_connect(SERVER, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
   }

}

 ?>
```

And a main class where I need to use the DB connection:

```
include 'includes/database.php';

class Main{

    var $mysqli;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->mysqli = new Database();
    }
```

But this is not working, since I get an error for queries that are still in the main classes, I intend to move them to the DB class later. But now I am getting an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   Database::query() in /home/vagrant/Projects/MyProject/index.php
>   on line 262

Queries are done in the Main class:

```
$result = $this->mysqli->query( "SELECT shops.*, shops.id AS shop,SUM(price)...
```

Comment: Access the query function as $this->mysqli->query();

Comment: We don't see usage of `query` here so we can not help you

Comment: A call to `query()` in the Database class must be as `$this->connection->query()` unless you write a `query()` method to wrap it directly in the `Database` class.  Please post the code where you're trying to call `query()`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I have added the query to the question

Comment: @Leff Okay, I fleshed out an answer.

Comment: @Leff why not just use the `mysqli` class directly, you are just limiting yourself by doing this.... you will at some point realize that all of this is useless.

Comment: @meda you are right, I just wanted some way of making this more flexible, and making one file for config stuff, where I would set the values for ```mysqli_connect``` method.

Comment: if you want flexibility, you can just use this class to create the connection and a getter method that will return the connection object, then call the functions direclty

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call a `query()` method on the `Database` class. While that class contains a `mysqli` object in its `$connection` property, it does not expose the `query()` method of that `mysqli` object.

Given your current code, you could drill further into the object structure to call `query()` directly on the `mysqli`, but this is messy.

```
// Call the query() method directly on the connection
$result = $this->mysqli->connection->query( "SELECT shops.*, shops.id AS shop,SUM(price)...
```

I don't like this approach because it requires that your classes know more about the inner workings of the `Database` class than they probably should. It couples them too tightly.

As an alternative, you could create a `query()` method in the `Database` class that wraps the necessary functionality of the `mysqli` object within it.

```
class Database {

   function __construct(){
     $this->connect();
   }

   public function connect(){
     $this->connection = mysqli_connect(SERVER, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
   }

   // Expose a query() method that calles the inner mysqli's query
   public function query($sql) {
     return $this->connection->query($sql);
   }
}
```

This would allow you to pack in more functionality, such as querying and fetching all result rows in one method call:

```
class Database {
   //....

   // A more featured query() that returns the
   // rows as an array
   public function query($sql) {
     $result = $this->connection->query($sql);
     while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $rows[] = $row;
     }
     // Return an array of all the rows fetched from the query
     return $rows;
   }
}
```

If you do it this way, you should be able to call `$this->mysqli->query("...")` as you originally attempted and either get back the result resource with the simple version, after which you must fetch in the code yourself, or get back an array of associative result rows in the more featured version.

Creating these kinds of database wrapper classes can get unwieldy rather quickly though.  Think carefully about what aspects of the `mysqli` object you want to expose to the other classes in your application. It's not a good idea to go down a path of wrapping every `mysqli` method in your `Database` class. At that point, the utility of the `Database` class is greatly reduced and you may as well just be passing in a `mysqli` object directly. If you are not actively adding functionality to `mysqli`, it makes less sense to create another class that wraps it.

A note about the `var $mysqli;`... This is an old deprecated class property syntax. The `var` keyword is a vestige from PHP4 and its use is discouraged nowadays. In fact, it has been removed from recent PHP versions.  Instead, you should declare it via the PHP5+ syntax:

```
// Declare as a public property
public $mysqli;

// Or better, as a private (or protected) property so it cannot
// be accessed outside the Main class' own methods
private $mysqli;
```

In your question title, you mentioned *injection*. Your class doesn't do that right now, but it would be a good idea to instantiate a `Database` ahead of time and inject one into the class constructors that need it.

```
class Main{

    public $mysqli;

    // Pass a database as a constructor param
    public function __construct($database){
        $this->mysqli = $database;
    }
```

Then instantiate it as:

```
$db = new Database();
// Pass the $db to the other classes
$main = new Main($db);
```

Importantly, this will prevent you from opening up a *separate* database connection for *each* object you instantiate of `Main` and any other class you construct in the same way.  Doing that can quickly use up the server's available MySQL connections.

Comment: @Leff does this make sense?

Comment: Very solid answer! I'd use `private $mysqli` instead of `public` so you can't access the property from outside the object to force loose coupling. +1 though

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ I agree, but didn't want to introduce too many concepts or change the OP's original methodology too much. I'll add another note about that.